# Diagonalization of matrices with integer entries

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, smith-normal-form

> Suppose we have a matrix $A\in M_{m\times n}$, with all integer entries. It is known that there we can diagonalize $A$ using row and column operations so that entries on the diagonal $(d_1,d_2,\ldots,d_k)$ are s. t. $d_1 \mid d_2\mid\cdots \mid d_k$ $(d_i\gt 0)$. Problem asks to prove that $d_1d_2\cdots d_r$ is the greatest common divisor of all determinants of $r\times r$ minors of $A$.

I proved this fact for $r = 1$, since column/row operations don't change $\gcd(\text{elements of }A)$. Now I'm stuck on the case $r\gt1$? How to solve it?

Comment: Well, you could use the formula: $\det A=\sum\limits_{p\in S_n}(-1)^{I(p)}\alpha_{1p(1)}\alpha_{2p(2)}\cdots\alpha_{np(n)}\\$ so, if you look at each summand, it's a product of entries s.t. no two entries are in the same row or column...

Comment: Oh, sorry. I misunderstood what r×r minors mean. I thought they were just "subsquares" (formed by adjacent rows and columns). Knowing they're rather artitrary, problem came up to trivial.

Comment: Afar, they are!

Comment: I think you could write $d_k=\color{red}{\lambda}\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^{k-1}d_i$